# Python - количество страниц в поиске по запросу

Tags: python, веб-программирование, seo

Всем привет. 
Картина вот какая: есть веб страница, поле input и кнопка. Пишем на Python 3.

**Задача:**

1. В input вводим запрос
2. Наживаем кнопку
3. в ответ нам генерируется страничка с полем input, кнопкой и (!) под ними в виде таблицы (3 столбца) выводит информацию - [Запрос, Количество страниц по запросу в Google, Количество страниц по запросу в Yandex]

**Вопрос:** с помощью чего программировать данный функционал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> с помощью чего программировать данный функционал?

Для подобной задачи Питон на сервере не нужен, достаточно фиксированную страничку с html `<form>` элементом отдавать, используя любой http-сервер, и немного javascript, чтобы запросы к google, yandex выполнить (если эти сервисы вообще открытое API для поиска имеют).

Если хочется именно Питон на сервере, то совершенно [любая web-framework подойдёт](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), например, используя [`bottle`](http://bottlepy.org/) (не тестировано):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, request, template # $  wget http://bottlepy.org/bottle.py

@route('/', ['GET', 'POST']) 
def index():
    query = request.forms.get('query')   
    return template('''
<form action="/" method="post">
     Query: <input name="query" type="text" />
      <input value="Search" type="submit" />
</form>
%if results
  <table>
   <tr>
   <td>{{query}}</td>
  % for count in results:
      <td>{{count}}</td>
  % end
%end
    ''', query=query, results=make_requests(query))

run()
```

где `make_requests()` функция делает запросы и возвращает кол-во страниц для каждого сервиса (например, как кортеж: `make_requests = lambda query: (10, 20)`).

Код представлен только для иллюстрации требуемых усилий: он не демонстрирует лучшие практики и может быть не точен в деталях.